# AndroidX.Annotation - Missing class, RequiresApi

Tags: flutter, androidx

In my Flutter apps I have frequently used the [Connectivity plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity/install) to check the current online state of the host device.  Up until recently this has always worked just fine.  However, with the latest Flutter upgrade, version 1.22.2 I find that attempting `flutter run` gives the error

> pathto:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-0.4.9+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
> import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi

and then

> ```
>                        ^
> ```

RequiresApi

I fail to see why this is happening.  The [AndroidX developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/RequiresApi) certainly talk of this class.   I should mention that I specity `minSdkVesion` 23 with `targetSdkVersion` as 28.  Flutter doctor reports no errors, Android SDK version 30.0.2 and Android studio 4.

Why is this happening and how might I be able to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solutution? I have the same issue.

Comment: When I created a new project with the latest Flutter version, 1.22.2, and then ported across all of my old code things worked.  On further examination I dissovered two things - the CompileSDKVersion in `android\app\build.gradle` should be updated to 29.  More important though - I found that I got this issue because I was missing out on `ic_launcher` in my resources.  For some reason the compile continued despite this missing resource and then threw up this non-sequitar.

Comment: I had this same error thrown up as well in Flutter. But after troubleshooting, i saw that in my earlier steps when i was trying to rename my package (com.example not allowed for android release), i missed out a semi-colon in my Application.java packages. Once i fixed that, this error was resolved strangely resolved as well. Guessing it's a chain reaction of other issues....

Answer (score 0):

in android/gradle.properties add below two line. in my case solve issue using this.

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true